# How to rotate outer ring of a matrix by n step in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, matrix

I want to rotate just the outer ring of a matrix clockwise.

Where n=number of steps to be rotate clockwise.

Suppose if I have a 4x5 matrix.

> 1 2 3 4 5
>
> 6 7 8 9 0
>
> 5 4 2 5 7
>
> 8 2 7 9 3

Now if n=1 the output should be :-

> 6 1 2 3 4
>
> 5 7 8 9 5
>
> 8 4 2 5 0
>
> 2 7 9 3 7

I have tried the logic of :

```
int temp = im[i][j];
          im[i][j] = im[n-1-j][i];
          im[n-1-j][i] = im[n-1-i][n-1-j];
          im[n-1-i][n-1-j] = im[j][n-1-i];
          im[j][n-1-i] = temp;
```

But I know this logic is completely wrong as it is moving the whole matrix.

Comment: What's `n`? Which direction, clock or counterclock?

Comment: edited @Ripi2 btw n=number of steps and clockwise

Comment: This shouldn't be that hard. First, find the connection between matrix size and ring length. Then find how to enumarate all elements in the ring. Then it should be simple.

Comment: Code snippet would be a great help @HolyBlackCat

Comment: Hint about `ì,j` indices: For a row in the outer ring `i=0` or `i=4`. For a col in the outer ring `j=0` or `j=5`. Not all i,j values represent a cell in the outer ring.

Comment: Yeah but how to replace the values . Whole code snippet would be a great help @Ripi2

Comment: Hint 2: Think of a 1D array. How would you move all cells?

Comment: you basically have two not so hard problems: First enumerate all elements in the ring, start at an arbitrary position (eg. top left) and find a mapping: index in the ring -> position in the matrix. Once you have this the rotation should be almost trivial

Comment: A code function will be helpful @Ripi2 as i m a begginer

Comment: Sorry, no. These kind of easy problems are there so as to exercite *your* mind, not *mine*.

Comment: @Vivank If you don't want to remain a beginner, start writing code yourself, not asking us to do it for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

- Map and copy the border to a flat array
- Apply `std::rotate`
- Copy rotated array back into the border

Here is a sample implementation:

```
void rotate_border(int m[R][C], int n) {
    vector<int> tmp(2*(R+C-2), -1);
    for (size_t c = 0 ; c != C ; c++) {
        tmp[c] = m[0][c];
        tmp[c+C+R-2] = m[R-1][C-c-1];
    }
    for (size_t r = 1 ; r != R-1 ; r++) {
        tmp[C+r-1] = m[r][C-1];
        tmp[2*C+R-3+r] = m[R-r-1][0];
    }
    std::rotate(tmp.begin(), std::next(tmp.begin(), n), tmp.end());
    for (size_t c = 0 ; c != C ; c++) {
        m[0][c] = tmp[c];
        m[R-1][C-c-1] = tmp[c+C+R-2];
    }
    for (size_t r = 1 ; r != R-1 ; r++) {
        m[r][C-1] = tmp[C+r-1];
        m[R-r-1][0] = tmp[2*C+R-3+r];
    }
}
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/KoGPi3)

Positive numbers rotate border counterclockwise. For clockwise rotation subtract the number from the size of the border. For example, 4✕5 matrix has the border of size 14, i.e. 5+(4-2)+5+(4-2). Hence, rotating by 1 clockwise requires rotating by `14-1`.

Comment: What values should be passed in R and C ?

Comment: @Vivank These are the numbers of `R`ows and `C`olumns in your matrix.